# Swift error when accessing UILocalNotification userinfo

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, option-type

I am trying to retrieve the currently scheduled UILocalNotifications.  I get an error when I try to implicitly unwrap userInfo from the notification.  The error happens on the line

```
          if let info = notification.userInfo
```

The error says "Could not find an overload for 'userInfo' that accepts the supplied arguments"

I also tried doing optional chaining with

```
if let info = notification.userInfo?["Id"]
```

And I got an error that userInfo does not accept subscripts.

It worked when I used explicit unwrapping after userinfo with

```
if let info = notification.userInfo!
```

But I wanted to avoid doing that.  Any help would be great.  The full method is below.

```
func test()
{

  let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
  let scheduledNotifications = application.scheduledLocalNotifications

  for notification in scheduledNotifications
  {
    println( "found it" ) 

      if let info = notification.userInfo
      {
        println( "in")
      } else {
        // no userInfo dictionary present
        println( "else")
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application.scheduledLocalNotifiactions` gives an array of `AnyObject` so you are missing a type cast to `UILocalNotification`

```
 let scheduledNotifications = application.scheduledLocalNotifications as [UILocalNotification]
```

Comment: I don't know if Swift has been updated on this, but `scheduledLocalNotifications` now returns `[UILocalNotification]?`, so type casting should no longer be necessary.